# What is the Taylor series expansion of Incomplete Elliptical Integral Second Kind (namely $E(\phi,k)$ and its inverse $E^{-1}(\phi,k)$?

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, approximation, elliptic-integrals

I am looking for the Taylor series expansion of Elliptical Integral Second Kind (namely $E(\phi,k)$ and the Taylor series expansion for its inverse? Are there such expansions? (in Mathematica the name is Elliptical $E(\phi,k)$)

I will use the inverse of Elliptical $E(\phi,k)$ to approximate to a polynomial or a function. In my case phi is unknown and k is known. 
So an expansion approximation or polynomial approximation of the inverse is also fine that will help me to find phi.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try code such as `s = EllipticE[x, k^2] + O[x^9]` followed by `InverseSeries[s]`?